# sed command failing in script with arguments

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed, string

I am trying to perform a two step string editing:

1. Match for the string "payload". If found, then add some "#if #endif" code as shown in output file.
2. Then copy the line containing "payload", replace it with "upper_payload" and then paste it within the "if endif" conditions.

Input File:

```
Let's see if this works or not payload.
alskdjaslkdjn.
aslkdjbnalkgfjbaglbjbjdgfsbkgjbsg;
Also here is another_payload.
alskdjbnalgkjb.
kjhsdfjlkgfjlknbsgdfljkbgsbljk((*&)(&;
```

Expected Output File:

```
Let's see if this works or not payload.
#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)
Let's see if this works or not upper_payload.
#endif
alskdjaslkdjn.
aslkdjbnalkgfjbaglbjbjdgfsbkgjbsg;
Also here is another_payload.
#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)
Also here is another_upper_payload.
#endif
alskdjbnalgkjb.
kjhsdfjlkgfjlknbsgdfljkbgsbljk((*&)(&;
```

I finally came up with the following code in a shell file so that I can run this on multiple text files:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
sed -i '/payload/a #if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)\n#endif' $1
sed -i "/NV_C2C_UPPER_PD/a `sed -n '/payload/s/payload/upper_payload/p' $1`" $1
```

With the above shell script when I pass a command such as:

```
> ./my_shell.sh test.txt
```

the text file is modified to the following output:

```
Let's see if this works or not payload.
#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)
Let's see if this works or not upper_payload.
#endif
alskdjaslkdjn.
aslkdjbnalkgfjbaglbjbjdgfsbkgjbsg;
Also here is another_payload.
#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)
Let's see if this works or not upper_payload.
#endif
alskdjbnalgkjb.
kjhsdfjlkgfjlknbsgdfljkbgsbljk((*&)(&;
```

And it also gives this error/warning on the terminal:

```
sed: can't read Also here is another_upper_payload.: No such file or directory
```

In the output we can observe that the second "upper_payload" substitution was incorrect because the line copying is incorrect. It copied the first line instead of the newer line containing "another_payload".

I have tried different options but I am failing in solving this problem. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: `sed` only or is `awk` ok?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to invoke another `sed` process to create input for one of your `sed` expressions, consider using the `s///` command to reorganize the current line as soon as you find the trigger substring (`payload`).

```
/payload/!b

s/.*/&\
#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)\
&\
#endif/

s/payload/upper_&/2
```

The above `sed` editing script starts by skipping any line containing our trigger string.  The `b` ("branch") command skips to the very end of the script when used without a label.

On the remaining lines, we replace the entire contents with itself, followed by the `#if` line, the original line a second time, and the `#endif` line.  One may insert newlines using the `s///` command if they are escaped as shown above (GNU `sed` allows for inserting literal newlines with `\n` too).

The second occurrence of the string `payload` is then prepended by the string `upper_` in a separate substitution.

This solution assumes that the trigger string does not occur multiple times in a single line, or the last substitution would not replace the correct substring.

On the command line,

```bsh
sed -e '/payload/!b' \
    -e 's/.*/&\
#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)\
&\
#endif/' \
    -e 's/payload/upper_&/2' file
```

or, using a separate script file for the script,

```bsh
sed -f script file
```

or, using a here-document for the script,

```bsh
sed -f /dev/stdin file <<'SED_SCRIPT'
/payload/!b

s/.*/&\
#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)\
&\
#endif/

s/payload/upper_&/2
SED_SCRIPT
```

or, using GNU `sed`,

```bsh
sed -e '/payload/!b' \
    -e 's/.*/&\n#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)\n&\n#endif/' \
    -e 's/payload/upper_&/2' file
```

Result:

```
Let's see if this works or not payload.
#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)
Let's see if this works or not upper_payload.
#endif
alskdjaslkdjn.
aslkdjbnalkgfjbaglbjbjdgfsbkgjbsg;
Also here is another_payload.
#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)
Also here is another_upper_payload.
#endif
alskdjbnalgkjb.
kjhsdfjlkgfjlknbsgdfljkbgsbljk((*&)(&;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `sed`

```
$ sed -i 's/\(.*\)\(payload\)\(.*\)/&\n#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)\n\1upper_\2\3\n#endif/ ' input_file
```

`\(.*\)\(payload\)` Here, the match is split into 2 groups so we can easily back reference them on the return

`&` will return the full match unaltered

`\1upper_\2` This is where we return the grouping in the order we require, the first group matches all the way to `payload` which allows `upper_` to be inserted before `payload`

**Output**

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)\(payload\)\(.*\)/&\n#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)\n\1upper_\2\3\n#endif/' input_file
Let's see if this works or not payload
#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)
Let's see if this works or not upper_payload
#endif.
alskdjaslkdjn.
aslkdjbnalkgfjbaglbjbjdgfsbkgjbsg;
Also here is another_payload
#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)
Also here is another_upper_payload
#endif.
alskdjbnalgkjb.
kjhsdfjlkgfjlknbsgdfljkbgsbljk((*&)(&;
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify this such that instead of grouping, we just replace "payload" with "upper_payload". One issue is that if I have text such as "random_payload_inserted", then the replacement gives this following weird output ```This a third line containing random_upper_payload
#endif_inserted.```  As we can see, anything upto the string "payload" is being printed followed by "#endif", which is not generic. Sorry, I didn't think about this case earlier.

Comment: @TapojyotiMandal Please check edit. If this does not address the additional condition, then please update your question with the relevant data that needs to be worked with.

Answer (score 1):

Great `sed` solutions here already, but I'd personally prefer `awk` for this:

```bsh
awk \
-v if='#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)' \
-v endif='#endif' \
'
/payload/{
  line=$0
  gsub("payload","upper_payload",$0);
  printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",$line,if,$0,endif
  next
}
1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using POSIXly only constructs:

```
sed -e 'p
  /payload/!d
  s//upper_&/
  i\
#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)
  a\
#endif
' file
```

---

If you don't want escaped newlines,
you can do as follows while still being
POSIXly compliant:

```
sed -e 'p
  /payload/!d
  s//upper_&/
  H;s/.*//;x;G
  s/^/#if defined(NV_C2C_UPPER_PD)/
  s/$/#endif/
' file
```